# HomeGenie Installation on Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, headless

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask, but it's kind of a cross between HomeGenie setup and integration with Ubuntu, so I hope I can get some good input or at least pointed in the right direction.

I installed HomeGenie (an open source home automation project) on my server, but I don't quite get the behind the scenes feel I'm looking for. I have to navigate to the HomeGenie directory and run `sudo mono HomeGenie.exe` to run the program. At this point the program works great for my purposes, however, my terminal is tied up with output from HomeGenie as it is used. If I interrupt (ctrl + c) the program exits.

I'm looking for a cleaner integration/install. I'd also like to set the program to start on boot. I'm using a headless server, so everything is done via command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as we solved this in the HomeGenie forum, I'm sharing the solution also here.
I added a note on *Running HomeGenie as a Background Service* at the end of *Getting Started* documentation page:

http://generoso.info/homegenie/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command not attached to the terminal by entering a `&` after your command so in this case `sudo mono HomeGenie.exe &` should work I think.

Comment: `sudo mono HomeGenie.exe &` gives output `[2] 5438` and I can't access the web page, so I assume it isn't running.

Comment: I tried using this guide: http://tempvariable.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-add-program-to-run-at-startup-in.html to start on boot (which uses the `&` but I didn't know what that was for). Either way, it doesn't seem to work.